# System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly - ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building a .NET Core project in a Docker container on Dokcer Desktop and getting error on this exited container (ASP.NET Core Web API):

> Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Catalog.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Here is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aa193207-78b8-45d6-aa17-725e3bd9939f</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
      <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
      
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Catalog.Application\Catalog.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Catalog.Infrastructure\Catalog.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Application/Catalog.Application.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Application/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Core/Catalog.Core.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Core/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Infrastructure/Catalog.Infrastructure.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API"
RUN dotnet build "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by changing the assembly name. It seems it had to be different from the folder it was copied in. I do not know why exactly but that solved.